# How to use a function inside another with nuxt plugins on the same file

Tags: function, plugins, nuxt.js

i want to know how to use another function inside the mainFunction

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
return {
    provide: {
        // my main function
        mainFunc: () => {
            return `hello ${anotherFunc()}`;
        },


        // i want to use this inside the main
        anotherFunc: () => {
            return 'Another Func';
        },
```

so, how can i use it, i hope to help me?